# WordPress page navigation using WP-pagenavi and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to get page navigation going, for posts which are displayed as an ajax response.

I'm not sure exactly how to accomplish this.

Here is some code to look at.

```
$posts_per_page = 6;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$pageposts = query_posts(
    array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'cat' => intval($_POST['pageCategory']),
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
));


if ($pageposts):
    $response = '';

    foreach ($pageposts as $post):
        $postId = get_the_ID();
        $postPermalink = get_the_permalink($postId);
        $postTitle = get_the_title();

        $response .= '
        <article class="gridView col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="list-article-thumb" style="background: url('; if ( get_the_post_thumbnail_url() == false ) { $response .= get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/placholder2.png'; } else { $response .= get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); } $response .= ') no-repeat; height: 445px; background-size: cover; position: relative;">

            </div>

        </article>
        ';
    endforeach;

    $response .= wp_pagenavi();
    wp_reset_query();

else :
    $response = '
    <h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
    <p class="center">Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn\'t here.</p>
    ';
endif;
```

The page navigation is returned as part of the ajax request but when I click on the next page button it goes to that page, rather than sending another request to ajax-posts.php

Cheers ol mates

Comment: "I click on the next page button it goes to that page"

--Have you stopped the default event from firing on click of that button?

Comment: No the page loads up fine but it takes me to the page `http://localhost/testwp2/wp-content/themes/my-theme/ajax-posts.php/page/2/` But that page doesn't exist because ajax-posts.php is a page to process the ajax requests and return the above code $response var

Comment: I think what I have to do is build my own pagination using js in the response but was hoping to use a plugin to make life easier.

Comment: So you're saying you dont want to be taken to that page correct? You need the Ajax to continue to fire and ignore the event of the button click?

Comment: yeah thats exactly it

Comment: Like I said, prevent the event from firing. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: So I will basically have to use my own custom built solution. Then I guess using WP-pagenavi is pointless then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so it seems using WP-pagenavi was pointless, was easier to build my own solution. It uses infinite scrolling.

Here is what I have done:

1. Initially I send the ajax request with a limit of 6 posts.

   ```
   var pageCategory = "' . $categoryId . '";
   $.post("/testwp2/wp-content/themes/my-theme/ajax-posts.php", {
       initialize: true, pageCategory: pageCategory, resultLimit: 6
   }).done(function(data) {
       $("#primary #main").html(data);
   });
   ```
2. On the ajax-posts.php page I process the request using the new limit var and include some jquery in the response.

   ```
   global $wpdb;
   global $post;

   $limit = $_POST['resultLimit'];

   $querystr = "SELECT {$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID, {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_title, {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_excerpt, {$wpdb->prefix}posts.guid, {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_date, {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_author
   FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts
   LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships rel ON rel.object_id = {$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID
   LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy tax ON tax.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id
   LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms t ON t.term_id = tax.term_id
   WHERE t.term_id = " . $_SESSION['pageCategory'] . "
   AND {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_type = 'post' 
   ORDER BY {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_date DESC
   LIMIT $limit
   ";

   $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);


   if ($pageposts):
   $response = '';

   foreach ($pageposts as $post):
       $postId = get_the_ID();
       $postPermalink = get_the_permalink($postId);
       $postTitle = get_the_title();

       $response .= '
       <article class="gridView col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
           <div class="list-article-thumb" style="background: url('; if ( get_the_post_thumbnail_url() == false ) { $response .= get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/placholder2.png'; } else { $response .= get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); } $response .= ') no-repeat; height: 445px; background-size: cover; position: relative;">

           </div>

       </article>
       ';
   endforeach;
   //This is the jquery to make infinite scroll happen
   $response .= '
       <script type="text/javascript">
           jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
               $(window).scroll(function() {
                   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - 50 == $(document).height() - 50) {
                       var pageCategory = ' . $_SESSION['pageCategory'] . '
                       $.post("/testwp2/wp-content/themes/my-theme/ajax-posts.php", {
                           initialize: true, pageCategory: pageCategory, resultLimit: 6 + ' . $limit . '
                       }).done(function(data) {
                           $("#primary #main").html(data);
                       });
                       alert($limit);
                   }
               });
           });
       </script>
   ';

   wp_reset_query();

   else :
   $response = '
   <h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
   <p class="center">Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn\'t here.</p>
   ';
   endif;
   ```

Comment: Hi! A question: as i see, you don't use the native wp ajax solution, like localizing & calling the admin-ajax.php -built in the core. What is/was the exact reason? Thanks! Best wishes.